# TFS 2015 Update 2 - Some widgets are not loading anymore

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We made the Update 2 of TFS2015 but we now have some problems on it.

- "New Team Project" link do nothing
- A lot of widgets fail to load and we can't create new ones properly (see images below)
- The "RELEASE" tab show nothing (but maybe it's what was expected)

Look like something gone wrong so if you know how to repair this, please share but if not, we also don't know how to restore TFS to Update 1 and we don't know how to update again properly.

Thanks for your help.

[image: widgets not loading]

[image: widget configuration is empty]

Comment: Do you have the pre-Update 2 TFS backups?

Comment: What message displays if you click on "More details"?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I got the same 'Widget failed to load' error, and when I clicked 'More details' there is a message: `VS402647: Widget took too long to load'`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Widgets failing, I did the following:

1. Go to: control panel -> "project name" -> work
2. Set the start and end dates for the current release.

After saving the changes I refreshed and my widgets worked again.